# How to embed flash into XNA on windows mobile

Tags: flash, windows-mobile, xna

1. Can I embed flash in [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA)? how?
2. Can I get data(flash game result) from the embedded flash?

Thanks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials.shtml

http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0709051&page=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1th question:

Its 100% possible to embed flash in XNA if person finds a SWFWiever for Windows Forms.I have written an article about xna-windows controls-wpf integration here:

[XNA-Windows Controls-WPF Integration](http://iersoy.com/Posts.aspx?PostID=158)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way directly (especially not if you want to deploy your code to an Xbox 360). Workarounds would include using a Browser (with Flash installed) and render the Data to a Texture. It was discussed in [this blog](http://blogs.xnainfo.com/post/WebBrowser-control-on-XNA-texture.aspx).

However I do not believe that this will result in a good performance. Other solution (but I do not know how they play with XNA) used by games like Crysis use [Scaleform](https://www.scaleform.com/products/clik). But it's not free and you might to a lot of magic to get it working. Also, this won't work on an Xbox 360.

P.S. There is also [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html). Same issues as with Scaleform, you would have to find a way to share your DirectX contexts.

Answer (score 0):

[Possible answer to question 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/pstubbs/archive/2009/01/15/convert-flash-animations-to-xna.aspx)